# How to redirect to specific jsp page based on database record

Tags: jsp, servlets

I m new to JSP and Servlet.
I m developing an application where user can prepare questionnaire.
I have a page where user enters questionnaire details like name, desc and type.
These details are  inserted in database and a questionnarieId is generated.
What I want is user should be send to draftQuestionnaire page with the newly generated questionnaireId.
Something like this:- response.sendRedirect("draftQuestionnaire.jsp?questionnaireId="+questionnaireId);

I have a page draftQuestionnaire.jsp and I m storing questionnaireId in session varialbe.

I dont know how to tell questionnaire.jsp to include questionnaireId.

Comment: do You want to say that you are not able to get ID of newly added record?

Comment: I got the Id by getGeneratedKeys but redirection throws a 404 where I know I m missing something to be added in draftQuestionnaire.jsp

Comment: can i have a snapshot of draftQuestionnaire.jsp code?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't clarified what does `questionnaire.jsp` do! Anyway, I assume that `questionnaire.jsp` is the form which your user fills, and you have another JSP `questionnaire_action.jsp` which is the place where you get form values once your user submits it.

So in `questionnaire_action.jsp` you can retreive all form values that your user submitted, and save them to database using JDBC. Once your values are saved, you can get the auto-generated `questionnaireId` using the `getGeneratedKey()` method of JDBC's `Statement` interface. Once you have the `questionnairId`, you can simply use the `sendRedirect()` method as you mentioned:

```
response.sendRedirect("draftQuestionnaire.jsp?questionnaireId="+questionnaireId);
```

Note that we are not doing post-submit form processing in `questionnaire.jsp` but in `questionnair_action.jsp`. Hope it helps.